# Populate Map With Firebase data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mapkit

I've seen variations of this questions but, no answer that is applicable to how I set my code up. I'm stumped on the solution and I NEEEEED to get this project done immediately. So, I'm asking for a helping hand.

What I'm trying to do is this:

Pull the coordinates from my Firebase array, set up like this: [FireBase Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktMOY.png)

My Main Feed is like this:

```js
//
//  FeedVC.swift
//  GotToGo
//
//  Created by HSI on 9/3/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 HSI. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import MapKit
import Firebase
import CoreLocation

class FeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var centerMapped = false
    var geoFire: GeoFire!



    var posts = [Post]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode.follow

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        DataService.ds.REF_VENUE.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            self.posts = [] // THIS IS THE NEW LINE

            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                for snap in snapshot {
                    if let postDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let key = snap.key
                        let post = Post(postKey: key, postData: postDict)
                        self.posts.append(post)
                    }

                if let locationDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                    let lat = locationDict["LATITUDE"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                    let long = locationDict["LONGITUDE"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
                    _ = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.10, longitudeDelta: 0.10))

                    print(lat,long)
                    }
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    //Brings up the user on the map after authorization
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        locationAuthStatus()
    }


    //Checks if app is authorized to get user's location data.
    func locationAuthStatus () {
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse {

            mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        } else {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        }
    }

    func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 1000, 1000)

        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
        if let loc = userLocation.location {
            if !centerMapped {
                centerMapOnLocation(location: loc)
                centerMapped = true
            }

        }
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?

        if annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "User")
            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "icon")
        } 
        
        return annotationView
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailCell", for: indexPath) as? PostCell {
        let cellData = posts[indexPath.row]

        cell.configureCell(post: cellData)
            return cell
        } else {
            return PostCell()
        }
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "previewSegue", sender: post)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if let destination = segue.destination as? PreviewVC {
            if let update = sender as? Post, let update2 = sender as? Post {
                destination.locationData = update
                destination.addressData = update2
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My code runs and I can get the Lat and Long printed but, I don't know how to add them to the map. Should I make another VC and put the data in there? I'm not sure what to change but, I'm under the gun and I need help!

Comment: How would I turn this into custom Annotations. MKPointAnnotation doesn't allow for custom annotations. I apologize for not being more specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following code after `print(lat,long)`

```
print(lat,long)
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
annotation.title = "Hello!" // if you need title, add this line
self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```